# "do that" stands for a negative action

Tags: anaphora

Can "do(ing) that" refer to a negative action in the following?

> I will **not** talk about your exam results any further if me **doing that** (= not talking about your exam results) will make you stop crying.

> A: Please do **not** go there. B: I will **do that**. (= I will not go there.)

If there's a difference between the above uses of "do(ing) that," can you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it makes no sense, because not doing something is not doing something, so it’s not something you can do.

Correctly, it would be:

> A: Don’t do that.

> B: Ok, I **won’t** (do that). [I.e. Not **will**, but **will not**.]

For the exam results question, try:

> I will not talk about your exam results any further if it will make you stop crying.

Using “it” instead of “doing that” would make this acceptable.

Comment: How about "I will not talk about your exam results any further if me doing that (= not talking about your exam results) will make you stop crying"?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Could I use "that" instead of "it" in the exam example?

Comment: Much simpler: **I will not talk about your exam results any further if you will stop crying**. (I find **if me doing that** a tough call. Imagine: **If me going to town will please you....** Ouch!)

Comment: @Apollyon You could use “that” but it’s a somewhat stronger word than “it” and would sound unnecessary.